# Merge Dropbox codebase into Github codebase

Tags: github, dropbox, integrate

I am working on a project that has its code both in Dropbox and Github. The codebase in Dropbox is the most recent. I basically want to merge the codebase from Dropbox into the codebase in Github. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean *merge*?

Comment: Yes, I meant merge. I have edited the above question.

Comment: And have you tried anything? What happened?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used KDiff to compare the two projects. However, Kdiff would show two files as different if they were not binary equals. So I had to manually click on each file to see if they were different in terms of text. This process was very time consuming. So was wondering if there was an efficient method. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just paste the code from Dropbox into your repo and see what Git thinks of it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll do so.